# SQL/BigQuery: how to avoid grouping multiple, non-consecutive members of a group?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm encountering an issue I can't seem to solve myself. I am grouping rows by location and timestamp, and finding the first and last timestamps for instances where an entity remained stationary. The issue is that for my current code, SQL groups together rows when the entity returns to a location it has been before.

In my example, an entity is at location -66.89 10.5002 at 2020-05-24 05:22:00 and then returns to that location at 2020-05-24 11:13:00. The result of the current query makes it look like that entity was in that location for the entire time, although the rows in between clearly show it moved. This is a conceptual problem I really don't know how to solve in SQL. I'm doing this in Big Query but I remember hitting a similar wall in SQL Server.

Code:

```
with selection as (
select 1 as id,TIMESTAMP '2020-05-24 11:13:00' as timestamp_, 'POINT(-66.89 10.5002)' as geom
union all select
1,TIMESTAMP '2020-05-24 05:22:00','POINT(-66.89 10.5002)'
union all select
1,TIMESTAMP '2020-05-24 05:25:00','POINT(-66.8881 10.4994)'
union all select
1,TIMESTAMP '2020-05-24 09:14:00','POINT(-66.8888 10.4958)'
union all select
1,TIMESTAMP '2020-05-24 07:37:00 UTC','POINT(-66.8873 10.5)'
union all select
1, TIMESTAMP'2020-05-24 07:52:00 UTC','POINT(-66.8873 10.5)'
)

select id,timestamp_,geom,
first_value(timestamp_)
    OVER (PARTITION BY id,geom ORDER BY timestamp_ ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS interval_start,
last_value(timestamp_)
    OVER (PARTITION BY id,geom ORDER BY timestamp_ ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS interval_end,
FROM
selection order by id,timestamp_
```

Result. Note the interval_start and interval_end for the first and last row

| id | timestamp_ | geom | interval_start | interval_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-05-24 05:22:00 UTC | POINT(-66.89 10.5002) | 2020-05-24 05:22:00 UTC | 2020-05-24 11:13:00 UTC |
| 1 | 2020-05-24 05:25:00 UTC | POINT(-66.8881 10.4994) | 2020-05-24 05:25:00 UTC | 2020-05-24 05:25:00 UTC |
| 1 | 2020-05-24 07:37:00 UTC | POINT(-66.8873 10.5) | 2020-05-24 07:37:00 UTC | 2020-05-24 07:52:00 UTC |
| 1 | 2020-05-24 07:52:00 UTC | POINT(-66.8873 10.5) | 2020-05-24 07:37:00 UTC | 2020-05-24 07:52:00 UTC |
| 1 | 2020-05-24 09:14:00 UTC | POINT(-66.8888 10.4958) | 2020-05-24 09:14:00 UTC | 2020-05-24 09:14:00 UTC |
| 1 | 2020-05-24 11:13:00 UTC | POINT(-66.89 10.5002) | 2020-05-24 05:22:00 UTC | 2020-05-24 11:13:00 UTC |

Desired result:

| id | timestamp_ | geom | interval_start | interval_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-05-24 05:22:00 UTC | POINT(-66.89 10.5002) | 2020-05-24 05:22:00 UTC | 2020-05-24 05:22:00 UTC |
| 1 | 2020-05-24 05:25:00 UTC | POINT(-66.8881 10.4994) | 2020-05-24 05:25:00 UTC | 2020-05-24 05:25:00 UTC |
| 1 | 2020-05-24 07:37:00 UTC | POINT(-66.8873 10.5) | 2020-05-24 07:37:00 UTC | 2020-05-24 07:52:00 UTC |
| 1 | 2020-05-24 07:52:00 UTC | POINT(-66.8873 10.5) | 2020-05-24 07:37:00 UTC | 2020-05-24 07:52:00 UTC |
| 1 | 2020-05-24 09:14:00 UTC | POINT(-66.8888 10.4958) | 2020-05-24 09:14:00 UTC | 2020-05-24 09:14:00 UTC |
| 1 | 2020-05-24 11:13:00 UTC | POINT(-66.89 10.5002) | 2020-05-24 11:13:00 UTC | 2020-05-24 11:13:00 UTC |

Comment: The 1st and the last row have the same id and geom. Why do you expect different results?

Comment: based on sample data in your question - show expected result please

Comment: @forpas who said anything about expecting a different result? I'm asking about how to split those results into different groups by leveraging the fact that the first and last rows do not occur consecutively on an order by timestamp_

Comment: *I'm asking about how to split those results into different groups....* and where exactly do you mention this in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
with selection as (
  select 1 as id,TIMESTAMP '2020-05-24 11:13:00' as timestamp_, 'POINT(-66.89 10.5002)' as geom union all select
  1,TIMESTAMP '2020-05-24 05:22:00','POINT(-66.89 10.5002)' union all select
  1,TIMESTAMP '2020-05-24 05:25:00','POINT(-66.8881 10.4994)' union all select
  1,TIMESTAMP '2020-05-24 09:14:00','POINT(-66.8888 10.4958)' union all select
  1,TIMESTAMP '2020-05-24 07:37:00 UTC','POINT(-66.8873 10.5)' union all select
  1, TIMESTAMP'2020-05-24 07:52:00 UTC','POINT(-66.8873 10.5)'
), pregrouped_selection as (
  select id, timestamp_, geom, 
    countif(flag) over(partition by id order by timestamp_) grp
  from (
    select id, timestamp_, geom,
      geom != ifnull(lag(geom) over(partition by id order by timestamp_), geom) flag,
    from selection 
  )
  order by id, timestamp_
)
select id,timestamp_,geom,
first_value(timestamp_)
    OVER (PARTITION BY id,grp ORDER BY timestamp_ ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS interval_start,
last_value(timestamp_)
    OVER (PARTITION BY id,grp ORDER BY timestamp_ ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS interval_end,
FROM
pregrouped_selection order by id,timestamp_
```

with output

[image]

As you can see  - I left your original query almost 100% as is  - just replaced `geom` to `grp` inside `over()` statement AND from `pregrouped_selection` which does calculate group number - grp

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there are at least two distinct values using window functions:

```
min(geom) over (partition by id) <> max(geom) over (partition by id) as has_moved,
```

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure how that relates to the issue. The issue is being able to derive the first and last timestamp for a device in a given location, but since the device and location are identical in the first and last row, the current code derives a first and last timestamp that cover a time when the device wasn't in that location. Maybe expand a bit on how your answer addresses that?

Comment: @Encomium . . . Within a time frame, this checks if there is more than one `geom` value.  If so, the thingee moved.